LazyColumn inside Horizontal pager not working as expected
I'm using a LazyColumn inside a HorizontalPager, but when I scroll and want to click on items immediately, nothing happens (here's the video: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/oDlHoHe1tN8).
Here's the code:
HorizontalPager(
    state = pagerState!!,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()
) {
    AssetsListView(
        assetsList = currentAssets.data ?: emptyList(),
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        onRowSelected = { asset ->
            callBacks.onCoinSelected(asset, false)
        },
        baseAsset = marketBaseAsset,
    )
}

@Composable
fun AssetsListView(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onRowSelected: (Asset) -> Unit = {},
    assetsList: List<Asset>,
    baseAsset: BaseAsset = BaseAsset.IRT,
) {
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalRippleTheme provides SelectRippleTheme) {
        LazyColumn(modifier = modifier) {
            itemsIndexed(
                assetsList,
                key = { index, value -> value.id }) { index, value ->
                val onItemSelected = remember {
                    { onRowSelected(value) }
                }
                if(value.symbol != BaseAsset.IRT.symbol) {
                    CoinInfoRow(
                        asset = value,
                        modifier,
                        onRowClicked = onItemSelected,
                        baseAsset = baseAsset
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Do you know why this keeps happening? The same issue can be found in the "Sunflower" app also.

You can write your own clickable event that is invoked before scroll with PointerInput by changing pass.
You can use scroll progress or add NestedScrollConnection to check more refined click if you don't want click to be invoked on every condition.

@Preview
@Composable
fun ClickPassTest() {
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState {
        3
    }

    val context = LocalContext.current

    val interactionSourceList = remember {
        List(50) {
            MutableInteractionSource()
        }
    }

    HorizontalPager(state = pagerState) {
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {

            items(50) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .indication(
                            interactionSource = interactionSourceList[it],
                            ripple()
                        )
                        .clickableCustom(
interactionSource = interactionSourceList[it])
                            {
                                Toast
                                    .makeText(context, "CUSTOM Clickable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show()
                            }
                            .padding(16.dp),
                        text = "Row $it"
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
fun Modifier.clickableCustom(
    pass: PointerEventPass = PointerEventPass.Initial,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource? = null,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) = this.then(
    Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
        coroutineScope {
            awaitEachGesture {
                val down = awaitFirstDown(requireUnconsumed = false, pass = pass)

                val pressInteraction = PressInteraction.Press(down.position)
                launch {
                    interactionSource?.emit(pressInteraction)
                }

                val up = waitForUpOrCancellation(pass = pass)

                if (up != null) {
                    launch {
                        interactionSource?.emit(PressInteraction.Release(pressInteraction))
                    }
                    onClick()
                } else {
                    launch {
                        interactionSource?.emit(PressInteraction.Cancel(pressInteraction))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
)


thank you for the response, but this will lead to unexpected behavior like clicking on an item when stopping the scroll is intended, or tapping on an item twice when trying to stop the list and click on an item as two intuitive operations (I want the exact behavior as the home screen in Telegram as a matter of fact)

"but when I scroll and want to click on items immediately" This snippet exactly does that. And if you have to check consecutive clicks which would also happen with clickable you should add some kind of time out, clickable by default does not check for any consecutive clicks nor have any delay for invoking next onClick. And telegram home screen works exactly as in your video. You can't click any item when scroll is being invoked. What this code does is ignoring anything scroll and invoking click immediately

What I mean is being able to click on an item as soon as I stop the list, but this happens after a delay, or after clicking on an item multiple times

seems like combining this with an enabled parameter that checks if the scroll is in progress or not yields the desired result:  val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()
val isScrollInProgress = remember {
derivedStateOf {
scrollState.isScrollInProgress
}
} and   if (up != null) {
launch {
interactionSource?.emit(PressInteraction.Release(pressInteraction))
}
if(enabled) {
onClick()
}
}

You don't need to use derivedStateOf with scrollState.isScrollInProgress because both corresponds to same thing. derivedStateOf is used when there are values that can cause recomposition on every frame such as scrollPosition or visible item index.

you're right. It's redundant
